# How do I get a distinct, ordered list of names from a DataTable using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have a `DataTable` with a `Name` column. I want to generate a collection of the unique names ordered alphabetically. The following query ignores the *order by* clause.

```
var names =
    (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
    orderby (string)dr["Name"]
    select (string)dr["Name"]).Distinct();
```

Why does the `orderby` not get enforced?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To make it more readable and maintainable, you can also split it up into multiple LINQ statements.

1. First, select your data into a new list, let's call it `x1`, do a projection if desired
2. Next, create a distinct list, from `x1` into `x2`, using whatever distinction you require
3. Finally, create an ordered list, from `x2` into `x3`, sorting by whatever you desire

Answer (score 58):

**The problem is that the Distinct
 operator does not grant that it will
 maintain the original order of
 values.**

So your query will need to work like this

```
var names = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
             select (string)dr["Name"]).Distinct().OrderBy( name => name );
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var sortedTable = (from results in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
select (string)results[attributeList]).Distinct().OrderBy(name => name);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try out the following:

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().select(dr => dr["Name"].ToString()).Distinct().OrderBy(name => name);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
var names = (from dr in dataTable.Rows
             select (string)dr["Name"]).Distinct().OrderBy(name => name);
```

this should work for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

To abstract: all of the answers have something in common.

OrderBy needs to be the final operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like that:

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(g => g["Name"]).Select(s => s.First()).OrderBy(o => o["Name"]);
```